# How do I get title to display when user hovers over word?

Tags: html, css, tooltip, title

Here is an example of the code:

```html
<p>Bob's <dfn title="Dog">canine</dfn> mother and <dfn title="Horse">equine</dfn> father sat him down and carefully explained that he was an <dfn title="A mutation that combines two or more sets of chromosomes from different species">allopolyploid</dfn> organism.</p>
```

How do I make it so if a user hovers the mouse over *canine,* *equine*, or *allopolyploid*, the title which I put using dfn title can then be displayed to the user so he knows what each of those more difficult words mean?

Comment: It already displays the title on hover

Comment: make `tooltip` for that

Comment: Must have been my browser that had a glitch, I loaded it up on another browser and now it works. Do you know how to make the hover fancier? Like maybe it could display red border or something like that, would that be in css then?

Comment: Check [qTip](http://qtip1.com//demos/) a nice plugin for tooltip.

Comment: @EdwardK.: It would be better if you could edit your question to add your new requirement mentioned in your comment above. As it stands, it seems that the current answers don't actually answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

> use `data-title` attribute instead of `title` and style it.

You can also style it using [css](/questions/tagged/css).

If you use just title you cant remove default title tooltip.

```css
dfn {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
  position: relative;
}
dfn[data-title]:hover:after {
  content: attr(data-title);
  padding: 4px 8px;
  color: #333;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  z-index: 20;
  white-space: nowrap;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #222;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #222;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #222;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #eeeeee), color-stop(1, #cccccc));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
}
```

```html
<p>Bob's <dfn data-title="Dog">canine</dfn> mother and <dfn data-title="Horse">equine</dfn> father sat him down and carefully explained that he was an <dfn data-title="A mutation that combines two or more sets of chromosomes from different species">allopolyploid</dfn> organism.</p>
```

Comment: That works. Do you know how to make the hover less generic looking, once, for example, "dog" is displayed?

Comment: @Edward K. see i have applied styling.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use the title as content for the :after psuedo then display this at the tooltip!

```css
p {
  margin: 60px auto;
}
dfn {
  position: relative;
}
dfn:hover:after {
  content: attr(title);
  background: #fff;
  padding: 5px 12px;
  border: solid 1px #ddd;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<p>Bob's <dfn title="Dog">canine</dfn> mother and <dfn title="Horse">equine</dfn> father sat him down and carefully explained that he was an <dfn title="A mutation that combines two or more sets of chromosomes from different species">allopolyploid</dfn> organism.</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's already like you want.

```
<span title="I am hovering over the text">This is the text I want to have a mousover</span>
```

On mouse hover the title is displayed.

Otherwise you can use https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/. 
Including jQueryUI.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
   $(this).tooltip();
});
</script>
```

Or you can try including bootstrap http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Hello This Will Have Some Value">Hello...</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the `title` to a data-attribute and using a pseudo-element seems the most logical

```css
div {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 25px auto;
  bordeR: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 1em;
}
dfn {
  position: relative;
}
dfn:hover:after {
  display: block;
}
dfn:after {
  display: none;
  content: attr(data-title);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  margin-top: -2em;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: lightgreen;
  padding: .25em;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Bob's <dfn data-title="Dog">canine</dfn> mother and <dfn data-title="Horse">equine</dfn> father sat him down and carefully explained that he was an <dfn data-title="A mutation that combines two or more sets of chromosomes from different species">allopolyploid</dfn> organism.</p>
</div>
```

Also this means that the `title' wont display as well as the new tooltip type object.

Note however that this method has some drawback as noted by the long `title` having overflow issues.